# Maximize div in ng-app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, maximize-window

There are several similar questions in the stack, but none of them seems helpful.
I'm looking for the right way (I would say ng-way) how to maximize the div. The best example in my case is ZEN mode on Github: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/new#fullscreen_issue_body

I have a bootstrap row with `ng-repeat` inside:

```
<div class="row">
    <div ng-repeat="widget in factory.getStack()" class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
                <h5 class="panel-title pull-left">{{widget.title}}</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div ng-include src="widget.uri"></div>
            <button ng-click="maximize()">Maximize</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

1. z-index is ok
2. jquery will help angular
3. ...

**Update 1**
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SIcAVfd07ThBSLq5FXzi?p=preview)

Any ideas will be appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the css of the div on click, add properties:

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
z-index: 999;
```

Example : [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dkXkj/7/)

Comment: Thank you! What if the div which has to be maximized inside another div/divs? http://plnkr.co/edit/SIcAVfd07ThBSLq5FXzi?p=preview

Comment: I updated my post. Add `z-index`, `top` and `left` properties on your css `.x-fill` class

Comment: I accept that, but markup has to be 'polish', because maximized div inherits its height from parent div (http://plnkr.co/edit/SIcAVfd07ThBSLq5FXzi?p=preview)